# Reloading a TableView's data?

Tags: objective-c, tableview, xcode4.3

I'm trying to build a hello world application with Xcode 4.3.

So far, I have a TableView (dragged and dropped from the objects list) and a TableViewCell (also dragged and dropped from the objects list).

I have an array too, and my TableView works and gets the data from array, but how can I reload the TableView's data? I tried `[self.tableView reloadData];` but it doesn't work. When I type `[self.`, `tableView` is not in my options...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have the NSTableView as a property of your class, you have to declare it as one.

In the interface of your class add:

```
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTableView *tableView;
```

In the implementation add:

```
@synthesize tableView;
```

Then in Interface Builder connect the table view to the tableView outlet of your class, by right clicking on "File's Owner" and dragging a line from "tableView" to your table view.

Comment: Great !! thank you very much , i changed NSTableView *tableView; to UITableView *mytableView; and then [self.mytableview reloadData]; did the work !!! thanks !

Comment: @invader7: You should accept the answer if it worked for you.